# Need to change the list items so they dont go directly down the page?

Tags: html, css

HTML is below

```
<div id="wrap">


<ul class="navbar">
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Franchises</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="">elroyz Xpress</a></li>
        <li><a href="">skye stickbeetles</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Juddamania</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Juddamania</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Juddamania</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Juddamania</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Juddamania</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Juddamania</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Juddamania</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Juddamania</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Juddamania</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Juddamania</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Juddamania</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Juddamania</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Juddamania</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Juddamania</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Fixtures</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="">Round 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 10</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 14</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 15</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 16</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 17</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 18</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 19</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 20</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 21</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 22</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Round 23</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Free Agents</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="">Adelaide</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Brisbane</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Carlton</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Collingwood</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Essendon</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Fremantle</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Geelong</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Gold Coast</a></li>
        <li><a href="">GWS</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Hawthorn</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Melbourne</a></li>
        <li><a href="">North Melbourne</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Port Adelaide</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Richmond</a></li>
        <li><a href="">St Kilda</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Sydney</a></li>
        <li><a href="">West Coast</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Western Bulldogs</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
</ul>
 </div>
```

CSS is below

```
#wrap {
    width:100%;
    height: 28px;
    margin: 0;
    z-index:99;
    background-color:#F00;
    text-align:left;}

.navbar {

    padding:0;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
    border-right: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
    border-left: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
}

    .navbar li  {
            width: 100px;  
            float: left;  
            text-align: center;  
            list-style: none;  
            font: normal bold 11px Arial, Verdana, Helvetica;  
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #F00
                        }

.navbar a   {                           
        padding: 7px 0;  
        border-left: 1px solid #1c1c1c; 
        border-right: 1px solid #1c1c1c; 
        text-decoration: none; 
        color: white; 
        display: block;


        }

 .navbar li:hover, a:hover {
     background-color: #900;
 } 

.navbar li ul   {
        display: none;  
        height: auto;                                   
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 0; 
        }               

.navbar li:hover ul     {
                        display: block;
                        }

.navbar li ul li {background-color: #a4a4a4;
}

.navbar li ul li a  {
        border-left: 1px solid #1c1c1c; 
        border-right: 1px solid #1c1c1c; 
        border-top: 1px solid #1c1c1c; 
        border-bottom: 1px solid #1c1c1c; 
        }

.navbar li ul li a:hover    {background-color: #1c1c1c;
}
```

The problem i am having is that the list items go too far down the page when hovered over the item. is there a way i can divide them into 2 or 3 rows so they go side by side ? only new to html and css and cant work it out myself. Thanks in advance

Comment: You could fake the columns using CSS positioning if you don't want the submenu items to be laid out horizontally. See my edited answer for a demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a good starting point is to adjust the width of the ul tags

add to the bottom of your css

```
ul{width:200px;}
```

check out this working example http://jsfiddle.net/Sj6Am/1

you can experiment from there..

Answer (score 1):

Please put your code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or something so it's clear what you're trying to do. Based on your code it looks like you've made a CSS dropdown menu but you have too much stuff in it.

Technically CSS3 [supports multi-column layouts](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_multiple_columns.asp). Practically speaking it's not widely supported yet so you should probably avoid it. There are a couple of things you can do:

1. **Make the inner `<li>`s display inline:** Not pretty but very easy. If you then put a `width` on the inner `<ul>` they will pop up in a box and look a little disorganized but usable.
2. **Switch to a smart `<select>`:** [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) is great for this. Add  "GO" button and the whole thing will take up less space without being hard to use. This will require javascript, but just one line on your part.

You could also manually split the list into several separate sublists and array them using floated divs, but that's finicky and more trouble than it's worth. You could also read [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/) ("How to Build a Kick-Butt CSS3 Mega Drop-Down Menu"), but again, I think that's more than you need or want.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a width to the submenu will give the list items more horizontal space to use.

```
.navbar li ul {
    display: none;  
    height: auto;                                   
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    width:200px; /* for example */
}
```

The browser will naturally lay out the list items across the container, so knowing how wide the container is you could re-order the list items to correctly display the *columns* you want.

**Edit:** It's <strike>a bit</strike> very hacky, but if the widths and number of list items in the submenus are known and are fixed (or at least don't change much) you could use CSS positioning to create pseudo columns, for example in [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EZEP4/)